# Вопрос с установкой файлов с интеренета на Python

Tags: python

Я сделал некий код. Он будет устанавливать фотку с интернета. Как сделать директорию устанавливаемого файла, чтобы не было начала, но есть одна или в крайнем случае больше одной папки, которые 100% существуют. Должна быть подгрузка файла в папку, которая существует вне зависимости от диска. Например: file\python\121.png

```
def WebDownload(self):
    from urllib import request
    import sys
    myUrl = "https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/2019/10/02/c14b657b053d4b6394a990e4cbd1c70a.jpg"
    myFile = "D:\\Python\\121.png"
    try:
        request.urlretrieve(myUrl, myFile)
    except Exception:
        print("Ошибка!")
        print(sys.exc_info())
```